# Is it possible to access estimator attributes in spark.ml pipelines?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I have a spark.ml pipeline in Spark 1.5.1 which consists of a series of transformers followed by a k-means estimator. I want to be able to access the [KMeansModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel).clusterCenters after fitting the pipeline, but can't figure out how. Is there a spark.ml equivalent of sklearn's pipeline.named_steps feature?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30478509/5376571) which gives two options. The first works if I take the k-means model out of my pipeline and fit it separately, but that kinda defeats the purpose of a pipeline. The second option doesn't work - I get `error: value getModel is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel`.

EDIT: Example pipeline:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

// create example dataframe
val sentenceData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("Hi I heard about Spark"),
  ("I wish Java could use case classes"),
  ("K-means models are neat")
  )).toDF("sentence")

// initialize pipeline stages
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features").setNumFeatures(20)
val kmeans = new KMeans()
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, kmeans))

// fit the pipeline
val fitKmeans = pipeline.fit(sentenceData)
```

So now `fitKmeans` is of type `org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel`. My question is, how do I access the cluster centers calculated by the k-means model contained within this pipeline? As noted above, when **not** contained in a pipeline, this can be done with `fitKmeans.clusterCenters`.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear! Would you care rephrasing with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @eliasah Ok, added an example.

Answer (score 24):

Answering my own question...I finally stumbled on an example deep in the spark.ml docs that shows how to do this using the `stages` member of the `PipelineModel` class. So for the example I posted above, in order to access the k-means cluster centers, do:

`val centers = fitKmeans.stages(2).asInstanceOf[KMeansModel].clusterCenters`

where `fitKmeans` is a PipelineModel and `2` is the index of the k-means model in the array of pipeline stages.

Reference: the last line of most of the examples on [this page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-ensembles.html).

Comment: this is ridiculous and awesome

Comment: Updated Link: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#tree-ensembles

Comment: To see all stages in pipeline: `model.stages`. If you know your ML is the last step, rather than searching for index, you can always do `model.stages.last`