# Spark access estimator in pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pipeline

Similar to [Is it possible to access estimator attributes in spark.ml pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220046/is-it-possible-to-access-estimator-attributes-in-spark-ml-pipelines) I want to access the estimator e.g. the last element in the pipeline.

The approach mentioned there doesn't seem to work any longer for spark 2.0.1. How does it work now?

## edit

perhaps I should explain it a little bit more detailed:
Here is my estimator + vector assembler:

```
val numRound = 20
val numWorkers = 4
val xgbBaseParams = Map(
    "max_depth" -> 10,
    "eta" -> 0.1,
    "seed" -> 50,
    "silent" -> 1,
    "objective" -> "binary:logistic"
  )

val xgbEstimator = new XGBoostEstimator(xgbBaseParams)
    .setFeaturesCol("features")
    .setLabelCol("label")

val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(train.columns
      .filter(!_.contains("label")))
    .setOutputCol("features")

  val simplePipeParams = new ParamGridBuilder()
    .addGrid(xgbEstimator.round, Array(numRound))
    .addGrid(xgbEstimator.nWorkers, Array(numWorkers))
    .build()

   val simplPipe = new Pipeline()
    .setStages(Array(vectorAssembler, xgbEstimator))

  val numberOfFolds = 2
  val cv = new CrossValidator()
    .setEstimator(simplPipe)
    .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setRawPredictionCol("prediction"))
    .setEstimatorParamMaps(simplePipeParams)
    .setNumFolds(numberOfFolds)
    .setSeed(gSeed)

  val cvModel = cv.fit(train)
  val trainPerformance = cvModel.transform(train)
  val testPerformance = cvModel.transform(test)
```

Now I want to perform a custom scoring e.g. `!= 0.5` cut-off point. This is possible if I get hold of the model:

```
val realModel = cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[XGBoostClassificationModel]
```

but this step here does not compile.
Thanks to your suggestion I can obtain the model:

```
 val pipelineModel: Option[PipelineModel] = cvModel.bestModel match {
    case p: PipelineModel => Some(p)
    case _ => None
  }

  val realModel: Option[XGBoostClassificationModel] = pipelineModel
    .flatMap {
      _.stages.collect { case t: XGBoostClassificationModel => t }
        .headOption
    }
  // TODO write it nicer
  val measureResults = realModel.map {
    rm =>
      {
        for (
          thresholds <- Array(Array(0.2, 0.8), Array(0.3, 0.7), Array(0.4, 0.6),
            Array(0.6, 0.4), Array(0.7, 0.3), Array(0.8, 0.2))
        ) {
          rm.setThresholds(thresholds)

          val predResult = rm.transform(test)
            .select("label", "probabilities", "prediction")
            .as[LabelledEvaluation]
          println("cutoff was ", thresholds)
          calculateEvaluation(R, predResult)
        }
      }
  }
```

However, the problem is that

```
val predResult = rm.transform(test)
```

will fail as `train` does not contain the features column of the `vectorAssembler`.
 This column is only created when the full pipeline is run.

So I decided to create a second pipeline:

```
val scoringPipe = new Pipeline()
            .setStages(Array(vectorAssembler, rm))
val predResult = scoringPipe.fit(train).transform(test)
```

but that seems to be a bit clumsy. Do you have a better / nicer idea?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `pipeline.getStages()` which returns all the stages in the form of an array. You can then access any stage you want. More information in [Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to obtain the trained best model from a crossvalidator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347875/how-to-obtain-the-trained-best-model-from-a-crossvalidator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing changed in the Spark 2.0.0 and the same approach works. [Example Pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#example-pipeline):

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0L, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
  (1L, "b d", 0.0),
  (2L, "spark f g h", 1.0),
  (3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)
)).toDF("id", "text", "label")

// Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setNumFeatures(1000)
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.01)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))

// Fit the pipeline to training documents.
val model = pipeline.fit(training)
```

And model:

```
val logRegModel = model.stages.last
  .asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel]
```

Comment: Ms problem is that I want to use the pipeline in a cross validation e.g. the estimator is nested twice. A `cvModel.bestModel.getStages` does not work. So how would I get the pipeline of a Crossvalidator then?

Comment: Then it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347875/how-to-obtain-the-trained-best-model-from-a-crossvalidator.